# How can I configure a three-piece comment?

Tags: comments

When editing an Haskell file, I want to configure a comment format `{- -}` such that:

```
{- <cr>
 - <cr>
 - -}
```

But it doesn't work as expected (but almost there):

```
{- <cr>
- <cr>
- -}
```

notice that after hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>, the `-` doesn't align.

What option should I use to make it aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. figured it out by looking into [haskell.vim](https://github.com/neovimhaskell/haskell-vim), I found ad slight modification of `indentexpr` would work.

check it out.

first,

```
$ cd ~/.vim/bundle/haskell-vim/
$ vi indent/haskell.vim
```

then find the definition of `GetHaskellIndent` function.

I add following lines right after the handling of `--` comment, therefore the function becomes:

```
function! GetHaskellIndent()
  let l:prevline = getline(v:lnum - 1)

  if l:prevline =~ '^\s*--'
    return match(l:prevline, '\S')
  endif

  if synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name") == 'hsBlockComment'
      for l:c in range(v:lnum - 1, 0, -1)
          let l:bline = getline(l:c)
          if l:bline =~ '{-'
              return 1 + match(l:bline, '{-')
      endfor
      return 1
  endif
```

starting from `if synIDattr(synID(line("."), ...` is my code.

basically what it means is check whether the current position is in block comment syntax, if so, get in the for loop and find the first occurrence of `{-`, then return the indent as deep as the `-` in `{-`.

notice that, my haskell environment is heavily customized. you should config according to yours. though my indent is setup to use `haskell.vim`, my syntax highlight is setup to use `vim2hs`. so it's better to look into the syntax highlight file first to find out what syntax element you should look at(in `vim2hs`'s case, it should be `'hsBlockComment'`, in `haskell.vim` it should be `'haskellBlockComment'`).

after having this code, I have following effect:

```
{-
 -
 -
 - -}
```

for comments in deep indent:

```
      {-
       -
       -
       -
       -
       - -}
```

works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of the comments is controled by the `comments`options (see [`:h format-comments`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#format-comments))

I think that your options are not properly configured, if you use the following command:

```
:set comments=s1:{-,m:-,e:-}
```

Your problem should be solved.

Lets decompose the options:

- `s` is for the start of three-piece comments
- `1` defines the offset to add to the middle and end part of the comment
- `:{-` defines the comment string of the first part of the three-piece comment.
- `m` is for the middle part of the three-piece comments
- `e` is (surprisingly) for the end of the three-piece comments.

This is a very minimal version of this option, please see the help topic linked at the beggining of the post to see all the magic you can do.

Originally my `comments` option was set to `s1fl:{-,mb:-,ex:-},:--`

Comment: your setting still doesn't make the `-`s aligned.

Comment: Hm that's pretty weird it works on my setup... I'll check if something else might interfere

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: Is `cindent` enabled on your system? (you can check with `:set cindent?` it will output `cindent`or `nocindent`) If it is enabled try disabling it with `:set nocindent` and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: `cindent` is not on indeed. but why would i need `cindent` on in haskell anyway? will `cindent` corrupt the indent config set up by other plugins?

Comment: Not you don't need it but when enabled it can mess your config, as I don't know your configuration I was just trying to find what could go wrong.

Comment: i use haskell-mode, which internally it should use haskell.vim to setup indent.

Comment: I was able to get the desired result by modifying the original _comments_ string a bit: `setlocal comments=s1fl:{-,mb:-,ex:-\ -},:--`. @statox's answer didn't align for me either even though `:h format-comments` seems to imply it should, but the modified original _comments_ string aligns correctly

Comment: @Jaymon don't hesitate to post that as an answer if that works better than the other answers :)